# What is the right way to draw bootstrap samples in instrumental variables regressions?

Tags: regression, bootstrap, instrumental-variables

I am considering a regression model 
$$y_i=x_i'\beta+\varepsilon_i, \quad E[x_i \varepsilon_i]\neq 0,$$
where I use the instrumental variables approach with instruments $z_i$ ($E[z_i \varepsilon_i]=0$ and $E[z_i x_i']$ having full column rank). So I have
$$\widehat{\beta}_{IV} = (Z'X)^{-1} Z'y.$$

Now I want to bootstrap a test-statistic... How do I draw bootstrap samples? Can residuals in bootstrap samples be drawn independently of $(x,z)$? If not, it is not clear to me what to do...

Comment: Here's a paper by Davidson and McKinnon on it:  www.iu.edu/~econdept/workshops/Spring_2008.../MacKinnon_rd-jgm-wildiv.pdf